# How to log CXF webservice requests to a different logfile?

Tags: java, web-services, log4j, cxf

How can I log all soap `CXF` xml requests to a different file than any other logging within my application?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console, MyFileAppender

log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=INFO, console
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=INFO, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO

log4j.appender.MyFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.MyFileAppender.File=c:/logs/logs.txt
```

Currently all logs go to the same file. I'd like to separate only the requests logging.

The general logging is done with: 
`Logger.getRootLogger().fatal("UNEXPECTED ERROR:", e);`

The CXF though just works by these interceptors. I'm not calling a specific logger myself to log the requests.

How can I write them to a different logfile? They should *only* appear in this file, and not in the general logfile anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf=false`

Answer (score 0):

To log to different files you can use Log4J [NDC or MDC](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/NDCvsMDC) or there is a build in feature for this in [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/)

Using MDC is easy, you need to put a key/value in MDC at the very start of the flow and also need to remove it at the end of the flow.

```
//start of flow
MDC.put("keyForCondition", "service 1")


//end of flow
MDC.remove("keyForCondition")
```

You can use this key's value for deciding which file to log in your customer Appender.

```
public class MyRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {  

@Override  
public void append(LoggingEvent event) {  
    String condition = (String)event.getMDC("keyForCondition");  
    String fileName = null;  
    if(condition == "service 1") {  
        fileName = "service1.log";  
    } else if(condition.equals("service 2")) {  
        fileName = "service2.log";  
    }

    try {  
        setFile(fileName, fileAppend, bufferedIO, bufferSize);  
    } catch (IOException ioe) {  
        System.err.println("Exception while setting service log file ")  
    }  
    super.append(event);  
}  
}
```